# ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError-could not obtain a database connection within 5 seconds

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, database-connection, puma

I have Rails 6 App and I get this error in production `ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError`.I did a bit of digging online and I understand that means database connection has maxed out.But I didn't get any clear solution for this other than considering increasing pool size in database.yml.(how do I know to what number)

Environments I use:

**Rails 6**

**Puma**

**Mysql**

deployed to AWS Rds **t2.micro** instance -**1 vCPU, 1 Gib RAM**

**database.yml**

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8mb4
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: root
  password: *******
  host: localhost
```

**puma.rb**

```
max_threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }
min_threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MIN_THREADS") { max_threads_count }
threads min_threads_count, max_threads_count

port ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }

environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }

pidfile ENV.fetch("PIDFILE") { "tmp/pids/server.pid" }
plugin :tmp_restart
```

Can somebody point me in the right direction, how do i resolve this, If the solution is increasing the pool size ,how do I calculate the number?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Rails 6 and mysql2?? why?

Comment: Try running ` ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections!` in your console. Note: console not terminal, so `rails c` first.

Comment: @BeulahAkindele Yes I ran it.Is there any specific detail you were looking for ? Here it is [#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool:0x0000559f70b0eea0 @mon_mutex=#<Thread::Mutex:0x0000559f70b0ec70>, @mon_mutex_owner_object_id=47071639402320, @mon_owner=nil, @mon_count=0, @query_cache_enabled=#<Concurrent::Map:0x0000559f70b0eae0 entries=0 default_proc=#<Proc:0x0000559f70b0e5e0@/opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:32>>, @spec=#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionSpecification:0x

Comment: Are you running the latest Puma?

Comment: @BeulahAkindele No I am using 4.1

Comment: I read something about a similar error a while ago (I'll try and find the link). It concluded at... it was fixed in the latest puma. Are you in a scenario where you can upgrade?

Comment: @BeulahAkindele No at the moment.I believe atleast, for now, can be resolved by proper configuration.That is what i am trying to figure out.